# Ternary operator '?:' deduces incorrect type in GCC versions pre 4.9.0?

Tags: c++, c++11, g++

The following code demonstrates a GCC issue (versions < 4.9.0) with the ternary operator:

```
static_assert(std::is_same<int, decltype(true ? std::declval<int>() : std::declval<int>())>::value,
              "Succeeds on GCC < 4.9.0");
static_assert(std::is_same<int&&, decltype(true ? std::declval<int>() : std::declval<int>())>::value, 
              "Succeeds on GCC >= 4.9.0");
```

The 2nd line is the correct implementation as (true ? int&& : int&&) should deduce int&& not int.

This can be demonstrated via [Godbolt's compiler explorer](https://godbolt.org/g/AGwj19)

Comment: which version of gcc?

Comment: GCC 4.6.3 and Clang 3.5.0

Comment: no-one should be using GCC 4.anything for c++

Comment: I don't see you doing `decltype` on `declval<int>()`, I see you doing it on the return value of `?`.  Why do you claim something different than your code is demonstrating, I am confused.

Comment: Ie, you are making claims about `static_assert(std::is_same<int&&, decltype(std::declval<int>())>::value, "what you asked")` which is completely different than the code in your question.  The code is a mixture of `declval` and `?`.  Which is your question, `declval` or `?`?  If `declval`, please [mcve] and remove all of the `?` noise.  If `?`, ask about `?` not `declval`...

Comment: In fact, [all versions of GCC with `declval` support](https://godbolt.org/g/zuYKc7) say that `decltype(declval<int>())` is `int&&`. VTC since the claimed behavior isn't reproducible.

Comment: Yakk: I included all the code because I didn't know where the issue was. As you can see by the answers below, the code was needed to figure out there was a GCC defect at some point. The static_assert calls call the CommonType template which does the declval<int> all at compile time.

Comment: @RichardHodges I wish. I'm required to use Ubuntu 14.04, and gcc 4.8, because it doesn't easily support gcc > 4.8. I did get gcc 6, though. I do all my work using gcc 6, then ensure it compiles on 4.8. It gets painful that I can't use C++14's `auto` in lambdas though

Comment: @Chadness3 that's a shame because ubuntu 14 is out of support and gcc4.8 is known to have a very buggy stl

Comment: I edited my question a week ago, why hasn't it been reopened?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Going by [Matt Godbolt's compiler explorer](https://godbolt.org/g/ekSSiL), GCC seems to change its mind over which assert to fire after version 4.9.0. So this appears to be a bug which was fixed some time ago.

Note that `declval()` is [defined as](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/declval)

```
template<class T>
typename std::add_rvalue_reference<T>::type declval() noexcept;
```

so I would expect the return type of `declval<int>()` to be `int&&`.

Answer (score 1):

The bug is in the ancient version of gcc.

this expression is the reason:

```
decltype(true ? std::declval<T>() : std::declval<U>());
```

The correct result of `std::declval<T>()` is a `T&&`.

`decltype(T&&)` is `T&&` because in this case T&& is an entity.

Comment: So to clarify is the GCC bug that decltype(true ? std::declval<int>() : std::declval<int>()) is int and not int&&?  Thisis supposed to deduce the common type.

Comment: that is correct in my view